# Minimize (firstA_max - firstA_min) + (secondB_max - secondB_min)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given n pairs of integers. Split into two subsets A and B to minimize sum(maximum difference among first values of A, maximum difference among second values of B).

---

Example : n = 4
{0, 0}; {5;5}; {1; 1}; {3; 4}

A = {{0; 0}; {1; 1}}
B = {{5; 5}; {3; 4}}
(maximum difference among first values of A, maximum difference among second values of B).

(maximum difference among first values of A) = fA_max - fA_min = 1 - 0 = 1
(maximum difference among second values of B) = sB_max - sB_min = 5 - 4 = 1
Therefore, the answer if 1 + 1 = 2. And this is the best way.

---

Obviously, maximum difference among the values equals to (maximum value - minimum value). Hence, what we need to do is find the minimum of (fA_max - fA_min) + (sB_max - sB_min)

Suppose the given array is arr[], first value if arr[].first and second value is arr[].second.

I think it is quite easy to solve this in quadratic complexity. You just need to sort the array by the first value. Then all the elements in subset A should be picked consecutively in the sorted array. So, you can loop for all ranges [L;R] of the sorted. Each range, try to add all elements in that range into subset A and add all the remains into subset B.
For more detail, this is my C++ code

```cpp
int calc(pair<int, int> a[], int n){
    int m = 1e9, M = -1e9, res = 2e9; //m and M are min and max of all the first values in subset A 
    for (int l = 1; l <= n; l++){
        int g = m, G = M; //g and G are min and max of all the second values in subset B
        for(int r = n; r >= l; r--) {
            if (r - l + 1 < n){
                res = min(res, a[r].first - a[l].first + G - g);
            }
            g = min(g, a[r].second);
            G = max(G, a[r].second);
        }
        m = min(m, a[l].second);
        M = max(M, a[l].second);
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

Now, I want to improve my algorithm down to loglinear complexity. Of course, sort the array by the first value. After that, if I fixed fA_min = a[i].first, then if the index i increase, the fA_max will increase while the (sB_max - sB_min) decrease.

But now I am still stuck here, is there any ways to solve this problem in loglinear complexity?

Comment: An example or two of sample data would help. Please provide.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for your suggestion. If it is not enough, i will find another example.

Comment: Computing the results for all consecutive subsets of the sorted array is the way to go, I agree. For that you have n^2 and then for the min and max of each resulting set_b another n, (there I think your code is not working). Thus O(n^3). By saving the relevant indices of set_b the third loop could be avoided. 
A dynamic program could be a way to reduce also the first two for loops.

Comment: 1) Looks like `n >= 4`, subset size of A >= 2, and subset size of B >= 2 as subset size < 2 makes little sense.  Correct? 2) Are subsets sizes obliged to be about equal or can one subset have size 2 and the other size 99? 3) Overflow of `a[r].first - a[l].first` a concern?  4) Are all values non-negative?  5) Why all `int` math yet `res` is promoted to `long long` in the return?

Comment: A geometric view of this problem: we have a set of points in the Euclidean plane and want to cover them with the union of two infinite strips (this union will be shaped like a plus sign: +), one vertical, one horizontal, minimizing the sum of the widths.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica 1) Each subset has at least one element. 
2) Subsets sizes can be different from each other. 
3, 4) 0 <= a[i].first and a[i].second <= 10^9 for all 1 <= i <= n.
5) Thanks for your optimization.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I do not think that it makes the problem easier. But it is quite an unique idea.

Comment: @MinhHien " Each subset has at least one element" --> What is the maximum difference with only 1 element?  0 or something else?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, the maximum difference with only 1 element is 0.

Comment: @Luka I have tried to prove my algorithm. I think that if we loop n^2 times for the min_first and max_first of set A, we can add all the element that min_first <= first <= max_first to set A. Because the less elements set B has, the less max_difference is. And of course the max_diff in set A is fixed for each loop.

Comment: I just assumed with the G,g you want to get the max different of set_b or something, but G,g will be the same value in you code, as well as m and M.

Comment: @Luka What do you mean? G and g will be the same value if and only if all the second values in set_b are similar, or set_b has exactly one element.

Comment: Is there anyone think about Segment Tree or some data structures? I am trying to take this approach: Loop n values of max_first(A), then for each max_first(A), find min (-min_first(A) + max_second(B) - min_second(B)) in O(log(n)).

Comment: @MinhHien sorry my mistake, your program is correct, I didn't get it in the first place. :)

Comment: There is a combinatorics point of view: if you take an array `arr1` ordered by first element and another array `arr2` ordered by second element, the mapping between both establishes a permutation of `[1..n]`. It is only worth taking as A the sub arrays of `[1..n]` that let exactly one hole in the permutation  of `[1..n]` (the hole will be B). This allows to skip a lot of sub arrays. I saw there are some data structures to work with permutations (for example, PQ tree) but I'm not experienced with those. Maybe someone can see a way through this point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach is an attempt to escape the n^2, using an **argmin** list for the second element of the tuples (lets say the *y*-part). Where the points are sorted regarding *x*.

One Observation is that there is an optimum solution where A includes index argmin[0] or argmin[n-1] or both.

1. in *get_best_interval_min_max* we focus once on including argmin[0] and the next smallest element on *y* and so one. The we do the same from the max element.

We get two dictionaries {(i,j):(profit, idx)}, telling us how much we gain in *y* when including `points[i:j+1]` in A, towards min or max on *y*. *idx* is the idx in the argmin array.

2. calculate the objective for each dict assuming max/min or *y* is not in A.
3. combine the results of both dictionaries, : (i1,j1): (v1, idx1) and (i2,j2): (v2, idx2). result : `j2 - i1 + max_y - min_y - v1 - v2`.

Constraint: idx1 < idx2. Because the indices in the argmin array can not intersect, otherwise some profit in y might be counted twice.

On average the dictionaries (*dmin,dmax*) are smaller than *n*, but in the worst case when x and y correlate [(i,i) for i in range(n)] they are exactly *n*, and we do not win any time. Anyhow on random instances this approach is much faster. Maybe someone can improve upon this.

```py
import numpy as np
from random import randrange
import time

def get_best_interval_min_max(points):# sorted input according to x dim 
    L = len(points)
    argmin_b = np.argsort([p[1] for p in points])
    b_min,b_max = points[argmin_b[0]][1], points[argmin_b[L-1]][1]
    
    arg = [argmin_b[0],argmin_b[0]]
    res_min = dict()
    for i in range(1,L):
        res_min[tuple(arg)] = points[argmin_b[i]][1] - points[argmin_b[0]][1],i # the profit in b towards min
        if arg[0] > argmin_b[i]: arg[0]=argmin_b[i]
        elif arg[1] < argmin_b[i]: arg[1]=argmin_b[i]
        
    arg = [argmin_b[L-1],argmin_b[L-1]]
    res_max = dict()
    for i in range(L-2,-1,-1):
        res_max[tuple(arg)] = points[argmin_b[L-1]][1]-points[argmin_b[i]][1],i # the profit in b towards max
        if arg[0]>argmin_b[i]: arg[0]=argmin_b[i]
        elif arg[1]<argmin_b[i]: arg[1]=argmin_b[i]
    # return the two dicts, difference along y,     
    return res_min, res_max, b_max-b_min

def argmin_algo(points):
    # return the objective value, sets A and B, and the interval for A in points. 
    points.sort()
    # get the profits for different intervals on the sorted array for max and min
    dmin, dmax, y_diff = get_best_interval_min_max(points)
    key = [None,None]
    res_min = 2e9
    # the best result when only the min/max b value is includes in A
    for d in [dmin,dmax]:
        for k,(v,i) in d.items():
            res = points[k[1]][0]-points[k[0]][0] + y_diff - v
            if res < res_min: 
                key = k
                res_min = res

    # combine the results for max and min. 
    for k1,(v1,i) in dmin.items():
        for k2,(v2,j) in dmax.items():
            if i > j: break # their argmin_b indices can not intersect!
            idx_l, idx_h = min(k1[0], k2[0]), max(k1[1],k2[1]) # get index low and idx hight for combination
            res = points[idx_h][0]-points[idx_l][0] -v1 -v2 + y_diff
            if res < res_min: 
                key = (idx_l, idx_h) # new merged interval
                res_min = res
    return res_min, points[key[0]:key[1]+1], points[:key[0]]+points[key[1]+1:], key

def quadratic_algorithm(points):
    points.sort()
    m, M, res = 1e9, -1e9, 2e9
    idx = (0,0)
    for l in range(len(points)):
        g, G = m, M 
        for r in range(len(points)-1,l-1,-1):
            if r-l+1 < len(points):
                res_n = points[r][0] - points[l][0] + G - g
                if res_n < res:
                    res = res_n
                    idx = (l,r)
            g = min(g, points[r][1])
            G = max(G, points[r][1])
        m = min(m, points[l][1])
        M = max(M, points[l][1])
    return res, points[idx[0]:idx[1]+1], points[:idx[0]]+points[idx[1]+1:], idx

# let's try it and compare running times to the quadratic_algorithm
# get some "random" points
c1=0
c2=0
for i in range(100):
    points = [(randrange(100), randrange(100)) for i in range(1,200)]
    points.sort() # sorted for x dimention
    s = time.time()
    r1 = argmin_algo(points)
    e1 = time.time()
    r2 = quadratic_algorithm(points)
    e2 = time.time()
    c1 += (e1-s)
    c2 += (e2-e1)
    if not r1[0] == r2[0]:
        print(r1,r2)
        raise Exception("Error, results are not equal")
print("time of argmin_algo", c1, "time of quadratic_algorithm",c2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** @Luka proved the algorithm described in this answer is not exact. But I will keep it here because it's a good performance heuristics and opens the way to many probabilistic methods.

---

I will describe a loglinear algorithm. I couldn't find a counter example. But I also couldn't find a proof :/

Let set A be ordered by first element and set B be ordered by second element. They are initially empty. Take `floor(n/2)` random points of your set of points and put in set A. Put the remaining points in set B. Define this as a partition.

Let's call a partition **stable** if you can't take an element of set A, put it in B and decrease the objective function and if you can't take an element of set B, put it in A and decrease the objective function. Otherwise, let's call the partition **unstable**.

For an unstable partition, the only moves that are interesting are the ones that take the first or the last element of A and move to B or take the first or the last element of B and move to A. So, we can find all interesting moves for a given unstable partition in `O(1)`. If an interesting move decreases the objective function, do it. Go like that until the partition becomes stable. I conjecture that it takes at most `O(n)` moves for the partition to become stable. I also conjecture that at the moment the partition becomes stable, you will have a solution.

Comment: I suspect there's a counterexample, and that it could be found by implementing this algorithm and comparing it to a provable algorithm on small random instances.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Could you explain your intuition for believing this algorithm is wrong, please ? From my side, I will try to implement it and compare to a brute force on small random instances.

Comment: It's surprising when local search guarantees optimal solutions. Not saying there can't be unimodality or a matroid or something, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I see. My fear is also that it gets stuck on a local optimum. But it's hard to think about a counter example. I will follow your advice and try to let the computer find the counter example.

Comment: It is a nice algorithm, consider the two sets being:
A: (0,0), (8,10), (9,10), (10,5) ==> diff=10

B: (11,11), (9,11), (20,20)       ==> diff=9
you cant move any element, but the best solution would be: 
A: (0,0) ==> diff=0
B: (10,5),(8,10), (9,10), ,(11,11), (9,11), (20,20)       ==> diff=15

Comment: your algorithm will not move (10,5) to B, being stuck in the local optima.

Comment: @Luka Thanks for pointing out. I am thinking: is it possible that some other start point make it always work?

Comment: I think the geometric view is useful, maybe some arguments of geometry can improve upon n^2.